# Defining a object's property based onanother object's property

Tags: javascript, function, object

I define an object called `anotherObject` with a function called `anotherFunction` based on the `someFunction` from the object `someObject`.

```
 var someObject={
 someFunction:function(){
     return this;
 }
};

console.log(someObject.someFunction()===someObject);//true

var someFunc=someObject.someFunction;
console.log(someFunc===someObject.someFunction);//true
//the function does not have the same context as that of the function called earlier...
console.log(someFunc()===someObject);//false

var anotherObject={
 anotherFunction:someObject.someFunction
};

console.log(anotherObject.anotherFunction===someObject.someFunction);//true
console.log(anotherObject[anotherFunction]()===anotherObject);//true;
console.log(anotherObject.anotherFunction()===someObject);//false
```

Firefox Scratchpad reports that the function `anotherFunction` is not defined.

Comment: (function(){})==(function(){})

Comment: `anotherObject[anotherFunction]()` is rubbish

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: How can I copy a function in one object to another object?

Answer (score 0):

That's the way JavaScript functions actually work, the `someFunction` is a function which its responsibility is to return the `this` in the current context, no matter what is for this one:

```
var someFunc=someObject.someFunction;
```

you can call it using call or apply with whatever context you like:

```
var myobj = {};
console.log(someFunc.call(myobj)===myobj);//true
console.log(someFunc.apply(myobj)===myobj);//true
```

no matter what you pass as the first argument in `call` and `apply`, your function would return that very object. So as you see your function does what it is supposed to do, but if you want it to always return your first object `someObject`, you do not need to use `this` keyword.

Read [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21763808/2877719) to the **`How does JavaScript .prototype work?`**, I have tried to dig into this concept in the first two parts.

And also this is one of the best resources you can find about this concepts:

[Understanding JavaScript Function Invocation and “this”](http://yehudakatz.com/2011/08/11/understanding-javascript-function-invocation-and-this/)

Comment: I would like to know why the function `someObject.someFunction` was not copied to `anotherObject.anotherFunction`.I do understand a little bit about call and apply

Comment: @user2309862: what do you mean by `was not copied`? when you create your fucntion like `anotherFunction: someObject.someFunction`, it just creates a reference to the original function.

Comment: you are saying that adding a property to a function which has been passed to a higher order function would modify the original function